# Aplicação em C Servidor-cliente para transferência de arquivo com socket TCP e thread

Tags: c, linux, arquivo, thread, socket

Gostaria de pedir ajuda do fórum para tornar seguro (criptografar) a transferência de um arquivo entre dois computadores. 
Abaixo segue o código fonte em C de uma aplicação cliente-servidor para transferência de arquivos usando Socket TCP porém sem criptografia dos dados transferidos. Vocês poderiam me indicar literatura ou um exemplo em C de como criptografar os dados transferidos?

É um projeto simples, com intuito apenas didático. Ele contempla Thread com sockets para conexão de multiplos clientes.
O servidor lista um diretório que é passado como parâmetro e a porta que escuta para permitir as conexões com os clientes. O cliente passa a porta, o endereço IP e o nome do arquivo que quer se obter do servidor.

Para compilar o código do servidor:

`gcc -o server server.c -lpthread`

Para compilar o código do cliente:

`gcc -o client client.c`

código C do servidor:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *connection_handler(void *);

#define MAX_MSG 1024

/*
 Servidor aguarda por mensagem do cliente, imprime na tela
 e depois envia resposta e finaliza processo
 */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Variaveis auxiliares para encontrar o arquivo a ser transferido.
    DIR *mydir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat mystat;
    //verificando se foi executando o comando corretamente
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "use:./server [Porta] [local]\n");
        return -1;
    } else if (!isdigit(*argv[1])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argumento invalido '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "use:./server [Porta] [local]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    mydir = opendir(argv[2]);
    //verificando se o diretorio existe
    if(mydir == NULL ){fprintf(stderr, "Argumento invalido '%s'\n", argv[2]);return -1;}
    char* aux1 = argv[1];
        int portaServidor = atoi(aux1);

   //variaveis
    int socket_desc, conexao, c, nova_conex;
    struct sockaddr_in servidor, cliente;
    char *mensagem;
    char resposta[MAX_MSG];
    int tamanho, count;

    // para pegar o IP e porta do cliente  
    char *cliente_ip;
    int cliente_port;

    //*********************************************************************//
    //      INICIO DO TRATAMENTO DA THREAD, localizaÃ§Ã£o e transferencia    // 
    //      do arquivo.                                                    // 
    //*********************************************************************//
    void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc) {
        /*********************************************************/

        /*********comunicao entre cliente/servidor****************/

        // pegando IP e porta do cliente
        cliente_ip = inet_ntoa(cliente.sin_addr);
        cliente_port = ntohs(cliente.sin_port);
        printf("cliente conectou: %s : [ %d ]\n", cliente_ip, cliente_port);

        // lendo dados enviados pelo cliente
        //mensagem 1 recebido nome do arquivo   
        if ((tamanho = read(conexao, resposta, MAX_MSG)) < 0) {
            perror("Erro ao receber dados do cliente: ");
            return NULL;
        }
        resposta[tamanho] = '\0';
        printf("O cliente falou: %s\n", resposta);

        char aux_nomeArquivo[MAX_MSG];
        //fazendo cÃ³pia do nome do arquivo para variÃ¡vel auxiliar. tal variavel Ã© utilzada para localizar
        // o arquivo no diretorio.
        strncpy(aux_nomeArquivo, resposta, MAX_MSG);
        //printf("ax_nomeArquivo: %s\n", aux_nomeArquivo);



        /*********************************************************/
        if (mydir != NULL) {

            //funÃ§Ã£o busca todo o diretÃ³rio buscando o arquivo na variavel aux_nomeArquivo
            //struct stat s;
            while ((myfile = readdir(mydir)) != NULL) {

                stat(myfile->d_name, &mystat);

                printf("Arquivo lido: %s, Arquivo procurado: %s\n", myfile->d_name, resposta);
                if (strcmp(myfile->d_name, resposta) == 0) {//arquivo existe
                   closedir(mydir);
                    //Reiniciando variÃ¡veis da pesquisa do diretorio para a proxima thread
                    myfile = NULL;
                    mydir = NULL;
                    mydir = opendir(argv[2]);

                    //**************************************//
                    //      INICIO DO PROTOCOLO            //
                    //*************************************//


                    mensagem = "200";
                    //mensagem 2 - enviando confirmaÃ§Ã£o q arquivo existe
                    write(conexao, mensagem, strlen(mensagem));

                    //mensagem 3 - recebendo que arquivo OK do cliente
                    read(conexao, resposta, MAX_MSG);


                    //**************************************//
                    //      FIM DO PROTOCOLO               //
                    //*************************************//

                    //abrindo o arquivo e retirando o tamanho//
                    //fazendo cÃ³pia do nome do arquivo para variÃ¡vel auxiliar. tal variavel Ã© utilzada para localizar
                    // o arquivo no diretorio.


                    char localArquivo[1024]; 
                    strncpy(localArquivo, argv[2], 1024);
                    strcat(localArquivo,aux_nomeArquivo);

                    FILE * f = fopen(localArquivo, "rb");
                    if((fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END))<0){printf("ERRO DURANTE fseek");}
                    int len = (int) ftell(f);                   
                    mensagem = (char*) len;
                    printf("Tamanho do arquivo: %d\n", len);
                    //convertendo o valor do tamanho do arquivo (int) para ser enviado em uma mensagem no scoket(char)
                    char *p, text[32];
                    int a = len;
                    sprintf(text, "%d", len);
                    mensagem = text;

                    //mensagem 4 - enviando o tamanho do arquivo
                    send(conexao, mensagem, strlen(mensagem), 0);

                    int fd = open(localArquivo, O_RDONLY);
                    off_t offset = 0;
                    int sent_bytes = 0;
                    //localArquivo = NULL;
                    if (fd == -1) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file --> %s", strerror(errno));

                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    while (((sent_bytes = sendfile(conexao, fd, &offset, BUFSIZ)) > 0)&& (len > 0)) {

                        fprintf(stdout, "1. Servidor enviou %d bytes do arquivo, offset Ã© agora : %d e os dados restantes = %d\n", sent_bytes, (int)offset, len);
                        len -= sent_bytes;
                        fprintf(stdout, "2.Servidor enviou %d bytes do arquivo, offset Ã© agora : %d e os dados restantes = %d\n", sent_bytes, (int)offset, len);
                        if (len <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //closedir(mydir);
                    while (1) {
                    }

                }
            }if(myfile==NULL) {
                    //enviando mensagem para o cliente de arquivo nao encontrado.
                    mensagem = "404";//file not found
                    printf("\n//*********************************//\n");
                    printf("Arquivo \"%s\" NÃ£o Existe no diretÃ³rio: \"%s\"\n",aux_nomeArquivo, argv[2]);
                    //mensagem 2 - enviando confirmaÃ§Ã£o q arquivo existe
                    write(conexao, mensagem, strlen(mensagem));
                    //sempre que termina de pesquisar o diretorio de arquivos a variavel myfile vai para null
                    // entao eh necessario preencher mydir novamente com o argv[2] com o diretorio de pesquisa. 
                    //caso contrario novas thread nao acessaram o diretorio passado em argv[2]]
                    mydir = opendir(argv[2]);
                    //
                    while (1) {
                    }
                    close(conexao);
                    //closedir(mydir);

            }
            if (mydir != NULL) {
                closedir(mydir);
                mydir = NULL;
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(resposta, "bye\n") == 0) {
            close(conexao);
            printf("Servidor finalizado...\n");
            return NULL;
        }


    }

    //*********************************************************************//
    //      FIM DO TRATAMENTO DA THREAD, localizaÃ§Ã£o e transferencia    // 
    //      do arquivo.                                                    // 
    //*********************************************************************//



    //************************************************************
    /*********************************************************/
    //Criando um socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Nao foi possivel criar o socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Preparando a struct do socket
    servidor.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servidor.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Obtem IP do S.O.
    servidor.sin_port = htons(portaServidor);

    //Associando o socket a porta e endereco
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &servidor, sizeof (servidor)) < 0) {
        puts("Erro ao fazer bind Tente outra porta\n");
        return -1;
    }
    puts("Bind efetuado com sucesso\n");

    // Ouvindo por conexoes
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    /*********************************************************/

    //Aceitando e tratando conexoes

    puts("Aguardando por conexoes...");
    c = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);

    while ((conexao = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &cliente, (socklen_t*) & c))) {
        if (conexao < 0) {
            perror("Erro ao receber conexao\n");
            return -1;
        }

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        nova_conex = (int) malloc(1);
        nova_conex = conexao;

        if (pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void*) nova_conex) < 0) {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }
    if (nova_conex < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Código C do cliente:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_MSG 1024

/*
 Cliente envia mensagem ao servidor e imprime resposta
 recebida do Servidor
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *received_file;
    received_file = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    ssize_t len;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int aba;

      if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "use:./cliente [IP] [Porta] [arquivo]\n");
        return -1;
    } else if (!isdigit(*argv[2])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argumento invalido '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        fprintf(stderr, "use:./cliente [IP] [Porta] [arquivo]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // variaveis
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in servidor;
    char *mensagem;
    char resposta_servidor[MAX_MSG];
    int tamanho;
    mensagem = argv[3];
    char* aux1 = argv[2];
    int portaServidor = atoi(aux1);

    /*****************************************/
    /* Criando um socket */
    // AF_INET = ARPA INTERNET PROTOCOLS
    // SOCK_STREAM = orientado a conexao
    // 0 = protocolo padrao para o tipo escolhido -- TCP
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Nao foi possivel criar socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Informacoes para conectar no servidor */
    // IP do servidor
    // familia ARPANET
    // Porta - hton = host to network short (2bytes)
    servidor.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    servidor.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servidor.sin_port = htons(portaServidor);

    //Conectando no servidor remoto
    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &servidor, sizeof (servidor)) < 0) {
        printf("Nao foi possivel conectar\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Conectado no servidor\n");
    /*****************************************/


    /*******COMUNICAO - TROCA DE MENSAGENS **************/

    //Enviando uma mensagem
    //mensagem 1 enviando nome do arquivo.  
    if (send(socket_desc, mensagem, strlen(mensagem), 0) < 0) {
        printf("Erro ao enviar mensagem\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Dados enviados\n");

    memset(mensagem, 0, sizeof mensagem);
    memset(resposta_servidor, 0, sizeof resposta_servidor);

    //Recebendo resposta do servidor
    //mensagem 2 recebendo que arquivo existe   
    if((tamanho = read(socket_desc, resposta_servidor, MAX_MSG)) < 0) {
        printf("Falha ao receber resposta\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Resposta recebida: %s\n", resposta_servidor);
    if (strcmp(resposta_servidor, "200") == 0) {

        mensagem = "OK";
        //mensagem 3 enviado ok
        write(socket_desc, mensagem, strlen(mensagem));
        //mensagem 4 recebendo o tamanho do arquivo;
        memset(resposta_servidor, 0, sizeof resposta_servidor);
        read(socket_desc, resposta_servidor, 1024);

        int tamanhoDoArquivo = atoi(resposta_servidor);
        printf("\nTamanho do arquivo a ser copiado: %s \n", resposta_servidor);
        aba = tamanhoDoArquivo;

    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Arquivo nao encontrado no servirdor'%s'\n", argv[3]);
        close(socket_desc);
        printf("Cliente finalizado com sucesso!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (((len = recv(socket_desc, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)&& (aba > 0)) {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof (char), len, received_file);
        aba -= len;
        fprintf(stdout, "Recebidos %d bytes e aguardamos :- %d bytes\n", len, aba);
        if (aba <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(received_file);
    close(socket_desc);

    printf("Cliente finalizado com sucesso!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado Stackoverflow.

Comment: Boa tarde Ronaldo, qual o problema com o código? Se este seu código for uma tutorial recomendo não postar como pergunta, não somos um fórum aqui, somos um Q&A, vou te dar uma dica, você pode formular uma pergunta sobre o assunto do teu código e você mesmo pode responder, mas isto conforme as orientações deste link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Nao há problema. Estou compartilhando um exemplo com a comunidade para ajudar outros que estiverem ao vão passar pelo mesmo problema que passei.

Comment: OK. Sinto muito.

Comment: Acredito que pode eliminar esse tutorial por estar infringindo as regras do site,

Comment: Vocês irão deletar o post?

Comment: Não Ronaldo, ele será apenas fechado pra não receber respostas, mas ficará ainda visível a todos :) - De qualquer maneira apenas você e moderadores podem deletar, no caso nenhum moderador irá deletar pois este tipo de ação é só feita em casos de SPAM ou Vandalismo. O teu caso é apenas uso errado do site. Se você quiser manter a sua resposta e o post aberto, então recomendo editar a pergunta e criar uma resposta, LEIRA ESTE LINK pra entender: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer :)

Comment: Quem sabe ano que vem tenha espaço para fazer isto aqui. http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/ Nem todos podem ter acesso.

Comment: Sua edição ficou estranha, como eu disse não somos fórum. Não somos um local pra indicar coisas, ou dar respostas baseadas inteiramente em opiniões, recomendo que leia o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answering e faça o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour